# Live Search in Rails 5.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, livesearch

I am working to get a live search up and running, but am having trouble. The search feature works fine when clicking the search button. I have looked at every stack question with live search. Here are two of the external links (reputation prohibits more) that I have tried:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

http://aymeric.gaurat.net/2010/how-to-develop-live-search-textbox-in-ruby-on-rails/

My search functionality as it stands is listed below:

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
<% end %>

<div id="grid-display">
  <%= render "products" %>
  <%= paginate @products %>
</div>
```

products_controller.rb

```
@products = Product.search(params[:term]).page(params[:page]).per(9)
```

product.rb

```
def self.search(term)
  if term
    where('product_name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

application.js

```
$(function() {
  $("product_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#product_search").attr("action"), $("#product_search").serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
  });
});
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript render("products") %>");
```

UPDATE:

application.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', (function() {
  $("product_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#product_search").attr("action"),  $("#product_search").serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
  });
}));
```

Comment: Perhaps you might like to include your relevant javascript.

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: I suspect you're going to need a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` or `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){...})` in your js (I don't use turbolinks, so you'll have to sort out which one works for you).

Comment: I'll add it and get back.

Comment: Updated application.js to include both options you gave. Didn't fix the issue. Still loads with the basic search bar though.

Comment: Should this: $("product_search input") be $("#product_search input")? It would help if you show your rendered html.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Do you want it automatically render result on input changed?

Comment: Did you every figure this out? If so, please post your solution :)